# Encrypt a 3 TB hard disk with Truecrypt

Tags: macos, hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt

I just bought a WD Elements 3 TB hard disk and wanted to encrypt the entire thing with Truecrypt (7.1a - Mac), using AES-Twofish-Serpent, Whirlpool as Hash Algorithm and Mac OS Extended as the filesystem of choice. I worked my way through the "Volume Creation Wizard" without any problems, but every time I click on the final "Format"-Button the following error shows up:

Error: The drive uses a sector size other than 512 bytes.

[image]

Now, I don't really want to create a volume, as suggested, but instead encrypt the whole disk. Did anyone have similar problems to that and can offer a solution? Would be great! Thanks!

BTW.: I found [this](http://lenlo.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/truecrypt-mac-os-x-advanced-format-drives-true/) blog post of a guy who made changes to the Truecrypt source and encrypted his disk successfully afterwards. Well, I'm not really comfortable with using his version...

Comment: Of course you’re creating a partition-hosted volume. Whole-disk encryption is available *only* for boot encryption.

Comment: The solution is to either verify his changes to TrueCrypt yourself or use one of the 3 possible solutions.  As Daniel points out whole disk encryption is limited to MBR system disks ( because EFI/UEFI/GPT isn't supported )

Comment: Both of you are right, my choice of words may have been a bit unclear. I am trying to encrypt the disks partition (there is just one because I formatted it that way), but even that is apparently not possible... @Ramhound, you are suggesting that I use one of the 3 possible solutions, but I that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. (And also the reason why I posted my question...)

Comment: I provided you a fourth option.  It seems like the person didn't publish his changes.  By the sounds of it should be easy enough once you get the build environment setup. The current (official) release does not have the capability of doing what you want how you want it.